# Rspec:count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to rspec testing. I need to write test code to create a new record and to check the count is 1.

I'm integrating rails with ios app.

In my registration_controller

```
@name = User.find_by_name(params[:user][:name]])
#params[:user][:name]] value from ios app
if !@name.nil?
    user = User.new("email" => params[:user][:email])        
end
```

In my registration_controller_spec

```
 expect {
        post :create, {:user => { 'email' => 'xxx@yyy.com'}}
    }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

The if condition in controller is not allowing me to pass the test.

```
Failure/Error: expect {
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

If I assign any sample value to @name in controller, the test is passing. Please let me know, am I going in the right path? If not, suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: Where did you save newly created user? And I bet you lost into `@name` and `user` variables. One time you assign `User` to `@name`, then assign it to `user`...

Comment: I'm getting the name from ios app and i have to check if the name is already present in User.if not, then i have to save the new user.this is what in my controller..user.save follow in next line I didn't mentioned above.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `find_or_create_by`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Your test doesn't provide a value for `params[:user][:name]`, so `@name` is nil, thus the line with `User.new` is never reached.
2. You never actually save the user that you instantiate, meaning `User.count` never changes.
3. The `@name` variable isn't really a name, but a `User` instance (if found).

You probably want to use `User.find_or_create_by` as Yevgeniy mentions. That means doing something like:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(:name => params[:user][:name]) do |user|
  user.email = params[:user][:email]
end
```

And for that to actually work you probably want your test to read

```
expect {
  post :create, {:user => {'name' => 'Mr. xxx', 'email' => 'xxx@yyy.com'}}
}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: I need another clarification,suppose i'm not finding name from User, else i'm getting name from any other API say linkedin and checking nil or not.Now how can i write test code.

Comment: I have no idea. If you have further questions, please create one or more questions with the necessary details and information, examples of what you've tried that didn't work, and how you expected them to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless @name
  user = User.new("email" => params[:user][:email])        
end
```